# Background image placement

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am trying to place a full background image on a site where the bottom of the image is the bottom of the browser without any being cut off at the bottom. I would like the image to be positioned bottom left with anything to the top or right cut off depending on the browser size. Currently when I try to do this IE cuts off the bottom because of the larger nav bar. I've tried many different ways with no luck!. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should post relevant code and state what you've tried.

Comment: sounds like we could solve this for you, but need some sample html/css. Try setting up a sample in http://jsfiddle.net/ and linking it here.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with a few simple CSS rules applied on the `body`:

```
body {
   background-image: url('path/to/your/background.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I was over thinking this for sure. Cheers.